# What's the use of suggestThreadPoolSize in twisted?

Tags: twisted

From what I understand, twisted is single threaded. Everything happens in a single event loop. Why do we require a threadpool if twisted is single-threaded?

If you know exactly why, (like the function deferToThread uses a thread), that would be great. But any pointers to articles or theory would be appreciated too! I couldn't find anything useful on the twistedmatrix website.